# Find char combination in array of strings

Tags: javascript

I want to know whether any combination of str x is in the arrays. One hit is already fine.

```
var x = 'ACBC';
var arr = ['X','AB'];
var arr2 = ['X','234','C'];
var arr3 = ['X','CC'];
var arr4 = ['X','BB'];

console.log(containsString(arr,x)) // true
console.log(containsString(arr2,x)) // true
console.log(containsString(arr3,x)) // true
console.log(containsString(arr4,x)) // false
```

Comment: What have you tried till now? Can you present your code?

Comment: what about `["BA"]` does that contain `"ABCD"` ?

Comment: `arr.some` should help you, but what exactly does "contains" mean to you? Being a [subsequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subsequence) of `x`?

Comment: BA is fine too. the string of the array has to be somewhere in X

Comment: @user3024814 If BA is fine, why is BB not ok?

Comment: cause there is only one B in x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could iterate the array with short circuit and spread the strings and check the position of the wanted characters.

```js
function containsString(array, string) {
    return array.some(s => [...s].every(
        (i => c => i = string.indexOf(c, i) + 1)(0)
    ));
}

var x = 'ACBC',
    arr = ['X', 'AB'],
    arr2 = ['X', '234', 'C'],
    arr3 = ['X', 'CC'],
    arr4 = ['X', 'BB'];

console.log(containsString(['X', 'AB'], 'ACBC'));       //  true
console.log(containsString(['X', 'BA'], 'ACBC'));       // false, see below
console.log(containsString(['X', '234', 'C'], 'ACBC')); //  true
console.log(containsString(['X', 'CC'], 'ACBC'));       //  true
console.log(containsString(['X', 'BB'], 'ACBC'));       // false
```

While the above works only for sorted strings, you need to sort in advance to use it with `indexOf` and a changingstart position.

```js
function containsString(array, string) {
    var sorted = [...string].sort();
    return array.some(s => [...s].sort().every(
        (i => c => i = sorted.indexOf(c, i) + 1)(0)
    ));
}

console.log(containsString(['X', 'AB'], 'ACBC'));       //  true
console.log(containsString(['X', 'BA'], 'ACBC'));       //  true now
console.log(containsString(['X', '234', 'C'], 'ACBC')); //  true
console.log(containsString(['X', 'CC'], 'ACBC'));       //  true
console.log(containsString(['X', 'BB'], 'ACBC'));       // false
```

Comment: this is awesome, saved my day!! Now I just have to learn what this means :-[

Answer (score 0):

You could compare char frequencies in `x` vs the frequencies of the candidate strings. Here's a solution with that:

```js
var x = 'ACBC';
var arr = ['X', 'AB'];
var arr2 = ['X', '234', 'C'];
var arr3 = ['X', 'CC'];
var arr4 = ['X', 'BB'];

function containsString(list, x) {
  let xFrequencies = frequencies(x);
  return list.some(str => {
    let strFrequencies = frequencies(str);
    return Object.keys(strFrequencies)
      .every(c => c in xFrequencies && strFrequencies[c] <= xFrequencies[c])
  });
}

function frequencies(str) {
  return str.split('').reduce((acc, c) => {
    if (c in acc) acc[c] += 1;
    else acc[c] = 1;
    return acc;
  }, {});
}

console.log(containsString(arr, x)) // true
console.log(containsString(arr2, x)) // true
console.log(containsString(arr3, x)) // true
console.log(containsString(arr4, x)) // false
```

(Thanks to Nina Scholz, I learnt about `some` and `every` :D)